# How to derive Darcy's law only in the case of saturated soil without derived all cases?

Tags: civil-engineering, mathematics, soil

How to derive Darcy's law only in the case of saturated soil in mathematical/theoretical way without having to derive all the cases?

I can only find the generalized theoretical proof for all cased but not its more simple version.

Here is its simple version I ask you to derive(This is coming from Introduction to geotechnical engineering by Das):

$$v=ki$$

Where $v$, $k$ and $i$ are the discharge velocity, hydraulic conductivity and hydraulic gradient, respectively.

Darcy's law is a constitutive equation that describes the flow of a fluid through a porous medium. The law was formulated by Henry Darcy based on the results of experiments on the flow of water through beds of sand, forming the basis of hydrogeology, a branch of earth sciences. But then I was only able to find the theoretical derivation of the generalized Darcy's law

Comment: It would help everyone if you added more to your question. What is Darcy's Law? What equation are you trying to end up at? Etc...

Comment: Are you asking how to derive darcy's equation via homogenization of the stokes equation?  If so, try reading this introduction to darcy's law from stanford university: https://web.stanford.edu/~csoulain/PORE_SCALE/Chap1_Darcy.pdf

Comment: @paul No, I am just saying that the answerer should including formal theoretical equation if needed.